# I made a webpage but have excess white space at the bottom, how do I get rid of this?

Tags: html, css, tags

[screen shot of webpage with excess white space at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX4Yu.png)

I have created this webpage but there is excess white space at thee bottom that I do not know how to get rid of.  I feel as though it has something to do with the width and height of either my body or main section in my CSS file but I am not sure.  Here is the code for my CSS file.

```
body {
background: url('black_gradient.png')repeat-x;
text-align: center;
height: 800px;
}
#main{
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
background: url('brown gradient.jpg')repeat-x;
margin: 25px auto;  
border: solid 2px #ff3819;
border-bottom: solid 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font: 24pt;
    color: #000000;
}
hr {
    height: 2px;
    color: #000000;
}
p {
    font-family:"Calibri";
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 48px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: you didnt add your css file here. Post the content of your style.css file

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the height from your body and #main or set them to auto

Comment: do you have any inline css in your html?

Comment: This worked! I removed height from my body but not my main, but after I did that it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay so another question, if I wanted my main to fill the page all the way down how would I do that? That is bringing the gold and white gradient all the way down the page

Comment: i cant see the whole page structure now so i'm not 100% sure but try setting the height to 100vh;

Comment: the height of both the body and main?

Comment: also what does vh stand for?

Comment: in the body, vh means viewport height. sorry its late

Comment: I tried adding 100vh in the body but it did nothing to the page

Comment: I still haven't resolved this yet, but will play more with it today

Comment: If you have any suggestions please let me know

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
background-size: cover;
```

I also recommend reading about gradients in css.

Comment: What do you mean?  Did I not implement the gradient image correctly in my CSS file?

Comment: No, but CSS has its own feature for gradients. Those gradients are rendered by browser engine. What is better - size of gradient is automatically set to the box size.
You can find more about it there: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp
 If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! When you say "Those gradients are rendered by browser engine" Are you talking about image gradients? Also how do you know if you are using HTML or HTML5, because I know some attributes of HTML do not work with HTML5, but I cannot identify when I am using which.

Comment: I meant those CSS gradients - they are faster and lighter for your website (this is really tiny boost but it is). You can find everything about html attributes on w3schools - which are not supported